# Why does server respond without headers and body when http status code 500 is set in php-fpm on nginx?

Tags: php, http, nginx

In php-fpm(5.6) on nginx(1.20.1), I'm making an API that responds with http status code 500, some headers and body of json type.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

http_response_code(500);
die(json_encode([
  'errorMsg' => 'Something went wrong',
]));
```

But it seems the server responds without the headers and the body as clients(at least Chrome browser) don't receive them.

I tried setting a http status lower than 500 like 40x, and it made the server respond with the headers and the body as I expected.

Do other servers/applications also omit headers and body in response with http status 50x? Or it's just a problem specific to either php or nginx?

Comment: Usually, 5xx errors are generated by server faults, they don't return any content. If something is wrong with the request, 4xx are dedicated (not authorized, no content, I'm a teapot ^^). But this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73917133/4698373 may interest you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if you comment the first line, which generates an error, with the consequence that no header can be sent after output.

```
<?
//header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

http_response_code(500);
die(json_encode([
  'errorMsg' => 'Something went wrong',
]));
?>
```

Of course, in the response there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, but we can see :
[image: headers]

and the correct output:
[image: ouput]

On my tests platform (`php` 8.11), `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` generates the following error :

```
Warning: Undefined array key "HTTP_ORIGIN"
```

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41231168/4698373) to understand why.

Of course, if I set `ini_set('display_errors','Off')` as first line, all seems working fine but no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is more present.

Comment: I know that depending on the user agent, `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` can be undefined. But my test bed is where it's always defined. And I'm requesting to a different origin, so I need to allow CORS by `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: Hum, did you try to set it via [nginx configuration](https://serverfault.com/a/176729/987415) instead of via PHP? @ChangdaePark

Comment: Do you mean you can respond with body via nginx configuration even when it's 50x?